# Waiting for jquery to load asynchronously before loading js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am using the following to load ads on my site

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var adWidth = $(document).width();
        google_ad_client = "ca-pub-6777348526535979";
        if ( adWidth >= 768 ) {
          google_ad_slot    = "3870513647";
          google_ad_width   = 728;
          google_ad_height  = 90;
        } else {
          google_ad_slot    = "1127560842";
          google_ad_width   = 320;
          google_ad_height  = 50;
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

It works fine but i think i can optimize the ad delivery further.I want to load the jquery asynchronously and thus the following script must wait for the jquery to be loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var adWidth = $(document).width();
            google_ad_client = "ca-pub-6777348526535979";
            if ( adWidth >= 768 ) {
              google_ad_slot    = "3870513647";
              google_ad_width   = 728;
              google_ad_height  = 90;
            } else {
              google_ad_slot    = "1127560842";
              google_ad_width   = 320;
              google_ad_height  = 50;
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

How can i accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var google_ad_slot;
    var google_ad_width;
    var google_ad_height;
    var google_ad_client;

    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        var adWidth = $(document).width();
        google_ad_client = "ca-pub-6777348526535979";
        if ( adWidth >= 768 ) {
           google_ad_slot    = "3870513647";
           google_ad_width   = 728;
           google_ad_height  = 90;
        } else {
           google_ad_slot    = "1127560842";
           google_ad_width   = 320;
           google_ad_height  = 50;
        }
        $("head").append('<script type="text/javascript" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>');
    });
</script>
```

After DOM will be ready and scripts (including jQuery) will be loaded, jQuery will call this `$(document).ready()` function, your values will be initiated and Google Ad script will be added to the `head` section of a document.

All modern browsers correctly load and run script after adding it to DOM.

Variables should be global to let Google script work with them.
You can also try changing `$(document).ready` to `$(window).load` if it won't work to become absolutely sure it has been loaded.

Comment: Will it work if there is `async` in  script tag for jquery.min.js

Comment: @user2650277 It seems like it will not :( In case of `async script`s, `$(document).ready()` fires after DOM is ready. Async scripts can be still not loaded.

Comment: Is there any way you can of where i can load all my scripts async so that it doesn't affect load time

Comment: @user2650277 You can add all scripts manually on `$(document).ready()` using `$.append` function or `$.getScript`. However, as I suppose, it is a bad practice. The best you can do it to load jQuery synchronously and load all other scripts asynchronously. I am sure it won't affect loading - `jquery.min.js` is a really light-weight library; moreover, it is static and it is properly cached by browser. jQuery 2.1.4 is being downloaded for 14 ms.

Comment: I think there is some issue with your code.Ad doesn't load and i see `'); });` instead

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is [AMD.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) AMD (asynchronous module definition) is a specification that allows Javascript modules to explicitly declare their dependencies and load asynchronously.

Probably the most famous implementation of AMD is [RequireJS.](http://requirejs.org/) Basically, you move your code from the `<script>` tag and change it as follows:

```
require(['jquery'], function($){
    var adWidth = $(document).width();
    // And the rest of your code
});
```

Beware though, that jQuery doesn't support AMD very well, so you'll have to jump through some hoops. There are [instructions](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) on the RequireJS website to handle jQuery.